# MVC visual studio <link> reference not working in cshtml page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

MVC project file references not working!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css"> or
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/assets/css/home-page.css") %>" />  not working. Code here >http://qa.wolfsonchildrenschallenge.com/
```

Comment: C++ in an MVC app would be quite interesting!

Comment: @RustyX You should have retagged this completely. MVC is about the pattern and VS is issues with the IDE. :)

Comment: I have worked in another visual studio project and I would reference links like this     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css") %>" /> Although this will not work in this project?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your root directory on server is same as on your local machine.
and another thing use ..\ to go parent directory